# SSIS Catalog Change Restore to Previous Version - params and connection managers

Tags: ssis, ssms

I'm new to SSIS and have a question in regards to the option to restore a SSIS solution from the "Versions" menu option within the "Integration Services Catalogs" option within SSMS. If I restore to a previous version, will the "Project.params" and my global connection managers also revert to how they were for that version? Or when restoring to a previous version will this restore my packages only?

For example, if the last and active version of my solution is currently version 10 and decide to restore to version 9. Will my "Project.params" and my global connection managers also revert to the state they were in when I deployed version 9?

Thanks

Comment: If you're reverting the project, you're reverting the *entire* project. Parameters are part of that project, as are connection managers.

Comment: @Larnu Consider puttig your comment in an answer, so that Ken can accept it.